# How do I define mongoengine DynamicField in strawberry graphql schema

Tags: python-3.x, mongoengine, strawberry-graphql

mongo-model.py

```
`class DataRecord(EmbeddedDocument):
    field = StringField()
    old = DynamicField()
    new = DynamicField()

 class Audit(BaseModel):
    data = EmbeddedDocumentListField(DataRecord)`
```

[graphql-schema]

```
`@strawberry.type
class DataRecordRead:
    field: str
    old: Optional[?]
    new: Optional[?]  


@strawberry.type
class BaseAudit:
    data: Optional[List[DataRecordRead]]`
```

What are types of old and new field?

I want to learn types of my dynamic fields